# Tensorflow saves only checkpoint file without other data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Using TensorFlow I make save each model snapshot to separate folder:

```
saver.save(sess, foldername)
```

TF saves at the beginning all data to the `foldername`:

- .data-00000-of-00001
- .index
- .meta
- checkpoint

But frequently - only the `checkpoint` file, without any of the hidden files.

Is it a bug? or I should use hidden files from other snapshot and this behavior is due to the memory efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this:

```
save_path = saver.save(sess=sess, save_path="data2/con.ckpt",
        global_step=None, latest_filename=None, meta_graph_suffix='meta',
        write_meta_graph=True, write_state=True)
```